# Having trouble rewriting php file with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have a URL that is `domain.com/s_cart.php?&pid=1` and `/s_cart.php?&gid=2`

How would i go about setting a `.htaccess` to rewrite `s_cart.php` to the following

```
domain.com/order/&pid=1
```

Tried the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/order([/]*)$ ./s_cart.php?gid=5 [L,NC]
```

Didn't work.

Basically I'm trying to add `domain.com/order?pid=1`

When the actual url currently is `domain.com/s_cart.php?pid=1`

Comment: now you have two domain.com/order/&pid=1 and domain.com/order?&pid=1 , which one you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^order\.php$ /s_cart.php [L,QSA,NE]
```

Match only against URI and query string will be appended as it is with `QSA` flag.

If you want to match `pid` only in query string , replace like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&pid=
RewriteRule ^order\.php$ /s_cart.php [L,QSA,NE]
```